# Matplotlib: Animate function output in steps

Tags: animation, matplotlib, jupyter

I have a function that outputs `return (x, y)` and i would like to animate the x,y pair, from beginning to end. E.g. such that the line 'develops over time'.

This is what my output looks like:

```
x, y = stephan()
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

And when I try to use a snippit of animation code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))

line, = ax.plot([], [])

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x, y = stephan()
    line.set_data(x, y[i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)
```

I get this quite boring output:

[image]

It is plotting something, but certainly not the x,y output. I think that I might be using the animate or init function wrongly? And strangely enough, I haven't been able to find any code that does this quite simply.

Comment: Always provide a [mcve] of the issue. Here we don't even know what `x` and `y` are. Are they floats, lists, arrays, strings? Also comment your code, what is `line.set_data(x, y[i])` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the call to `stephan` returns two floats, `y[i]` does not make any sense. Furthermore you would want to store the output in a list, to obtain a line and not a single dot per frame.

A working example could look like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

class Stephan():
    i=0
    def __call__(self):
        self.i += 0.02
        return self.i, np.random.randn(1)

stephan = Stephan()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))

line, = ax.plot([], [])

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

X = []
def animate(i):
    x, y = stephan()
    X.append((x,y))
    line.set_data(zip(*X))
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Alternatively, if `stephan` returns two lists of values, you could directly set those lists as data to the line.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np

class Stephan():
    x=[0]
    y=[1]
    def __call__(self):
        self.x.append(self.x[-1]+0.02)
        self.y.append(np.random.randn(1))
        return self.x, self.y

stephan = Stephan()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))

line, = ax.plot([], [])

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x, y = stephan()
    line.set_data(x,y)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```